# colour mismatch in ssrs report and excel sheet

Tags: reporting-services

I have a ssrs report where i have used some colour formatting.The problem is that it is showing fine in the preview tab but when i am exporting it into excel sheet the colour is getting changed.Please help me.

Comment: What are the colours that you see? Are they different shades of the same color, or completely different?

Comment: Excel only has limited colours it can show. Also telling us what version of SSRS and Excel could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS + Excel Colors are a strange combination, you will probably have hard times having the same output in Excel as in SSRS. See this post: http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/excel-export-copy-to-another-excel-discoloration-issue-for-ssrs-2008-23790.shtml